# Python, Numpy: Cannot assign the values of a numpy array to a column of a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'n new to Python, and there is a syntax problem I'm trying to understand.
I have a numpy matrix:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 6],
              [2, 4, 5, 6], 
              [3, 8, 7, 6]])
```

An I want to apply a **Softmax** function to each column of it.
The code is pretty straightforward. Without reporting the whole loop, let's say I make it for the first column:

```
w = x[:,0]  # select a column
w = np.exp(w)  # compute softmax in two steps
w = w/sum(w)
x[:,0] = w   # reassign the values to the original matrix
```

However, instead of the values of `w: array([0.09003057, 0.24472847, 0.66524096])` , only a column of zeros is assigned to the matrix, that returns:

```
 np.array([[0, 2, 3, 6],
           [0, 4, 5, 6], 
           [0, 8, 7, 6]])
```

Why is that? How can I correct this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Change the dataype to float and then assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of values of your matrix is `int`, and at the time of assigning, the softmax values are converted to `int`, hence the zeros.

Create your matrix like this:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 6],
              [2, 4, 5, 6], 
              [3, 8, 7, 6]]).astype(float)
```

Now, after assigning softmax values:

```
w = x[:,0]  # select a column
w = np.exp(w)  # compute softmax in two steps
w = w/sum(w)
x[:,0] = w   # reassign the values to the original matrix
```

`x` comes out to be:

```
array([[0.09003057, 2., 3., 6.],
       [0.24472847, 4., 5., 6.],
       [0.66524096, 8., 7., 6.]])
```